# How to right align text with linebreaks in HTML FlexBox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a website with HTML and want to vertical align the content of a label using FlexBox.
As long as the contents have no 
 inside it works fine.
But when i got a content like

```html
Right<br/>Bottom<br/>24
```

the content is handled as a block which is right aligned, but the individual parts of the content are not right aligned at all.
I get per example:

```
Right
Bottom
24
```

instead of

```
Right
Bottom
    24
```

Here the style which i'm using for the label:

```html
display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: flex-end;
```

Have i forgotten something in the style?

Comment: text-align:right on the div

Comment: @TemaniAfif: Thanks a lot! It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put your content inside HTML element's because flexbox is not ment to work with just text if you wanna aplly your structure on a text use css **columns** instead of flexbox.